localhost ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR rest service
I have four different REST services developed in C#. When I run the REST services from Vsisual Studio and conect them from my angualr application, no problem.
Now, I change my pc and my browser give me a ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when I call one REST service. The other three services running with no problems.
Only for the one service chrome gives me this error. What can I check? Where is the problem?
What can I check? Where is the problem?
